# Have One Struct Point To Another

Tags: c++, struct, linked-list

I am having problems creating two structs, one is called a Bag and another is Card. This is what I have so far:

```
struct Card 
{
   char suit;
   int value;

};

struct BagNode
{
   Card* Card;
   BagNode* next;
};

void fillWithCards(BagNode *&head, BagNode *&tail, BagNode *&temp) 
{
char suits [] = {'s', 'h', 'd', 'c'};
int val [] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13};

for (int x = 0; x < 4 ; x++)
{
    for (int y =1 ; y <= 13 ; y++)
    {
        BagNode *now = new BagNode;
        now -> Card -> suit = suits [x];
        now -> Card -> value = val [y]; 

        if (*&head == NULL && *&tail == NULL && *&temp == NULL)
        {               
            head = now;
            tail = now;
            temp = now;
        }
        else if (*&tail != NULL && *&temp != NULL)
        {
            tail -> next = now;
            temp -> next = now;
            tail = now;
            temp = now;
        }
        else 
        {
            tail -> next = NULL;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that when I compile and run the program it would crash. I have a feeling the problem is related to `Card* Card;`

Yes, I know that I can have everything in Card i.e `*next` in there and I would not need a `BagNode`. However, upon asking my professor he said that we need to have two structs one for the `Bag` and another for the `Card`.

Comment: This is the perfect time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Why do you have a linked list of multiple Bags with only 1 card per Bag? What is that Bag supposed to represent? A single Bag with multiple cards in it would make more sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

```
BagNode *now = new BagNode;
```

This constructs a new instance of `BagNode` in dynamic scope. This class does not have a constructor. None of this class's members have a default constructor. Therefore, a new instance of this class is completely uninitialized. Immediately afterwards:

```
now -> Card -> suit = suits [x];
now -> Card -> value = val [y];
```

Since the new instance of the class is completely uninitialized, this attempts to dereference its completely uninitialized `Card` member, a pointer, resulting in undefined behavior, an uninitialized pointer dereference, and the obvious crash.

There may be other problems in the shown code, but it is not possible to conclusively analyze them, since a [Minimum, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) was not provided. The only other comment that can be made:

```
if (*&head == NULL && *&tail == NULL && *&temp == NULL)
```

The `*&` part accomplishes absolutely nothing useful. This is logically equivalent to:

```
if (head == NULL && tail == NULL && temp == NULL)
```

and this, of course, is much more readable and clear.

Answer (score 1):

You are not initializing `now->Card` to point at a valid `Card` instance before dereferencing the `Card*` pointer with `operator->`.  `now->Card` is an uninitialized pointer, so `Card->` is accessing invalid memory.

You are also not initializing `now->next`, either.  For a new node that hasn't been inserted into the list yet, it should be initialized to NULL since no node follows it yet.

I would  suggest changing `Card* Card;` to `Card card;`, and then use `operator.` instead of `operator->` to access the `Card` fields:

```
struct BagNode
{
   Card card; // <-- no '*' !
   BagNode* next;
};

...

BagNode *now = new BagNode;
now->Card.suit = suits [x];
now->Card.value = val [y]; 
now->next = NULL; // <-- don't forget this!
```

Now, with that said, the rest of your code doesn't make sense.  It is not a good linked-list insertion, and your use of the `temp` parameter just confuses it more.  What is `temp` supposed to represent?  The code will crash if `head/tail` are NULL but `temp` is not NULL.  `temp` just doesn't belong in this kind of code.

You are also going out of bounds of the `val[]` array.  Arrays are 0-indexed, not 1-indexed.  `val[]` has 13 elements, so valid indexes are 0-12, not 1-13.

Try something more like this instead:

```
struct Card 
{
   char suit;
   int value;
};

struct Bag
{
   Card card;
   Bag* next;
};

void fillWithCards(Bag* &head, Bag* &tail) 
{
    const char suits[] = {'s', 'h', 'd', 'c'};
    const int val[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13};

    for (int x = 0; x < 4 ; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 13; y++)
        {
            Bag *b = new Bag;
            b->card.suit = suits[x];
            b->card.value = val[y]; 
            b->next = NULL;

            if (!head)
                head = b;

            if (tail)
                tail->next = b;
            tail = b;
        }
    }
}
```